# Elasticsearch Restrict mapping so that only an single entity is inserted rather than an array

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field which strictly needs to be a single entity. But elasticsearch accepts array as well while indexing. Can I restrict this behaviour such that only one element can be inserted.